# How can I cast an instance of an at runtime loaded class from a dll in C#?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm loading serveral `.dll` files at the start of my application. At the moment I do that by using the following approach.

```
private void _loadConfiguration()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"pathToMyDll");
    Type? type = assembly.GetType("pathToMyClass");
    dynamic? clazz = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    dynamic? response = clazz.myMethod("Lorem", "Ipsum");
}
```

Nevertheless I want to cast the return value of `Activator.CreateInstance(type);`, since I do know that each class I am loading references an interface called `Kernpruefung`, eg.:

```
public class KernpruefungEEL10Impl : Object, Kernpruefung
{
    // code
}
```

Anyways I am not able to cast it, eg.:

```
Kernpruefung? clazz = (Kernpruefung)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

The above results into the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: "Unable to cast object of type 'de.aoksystems.da.kernpruefung.eel10.KernpruefungEEL10Impl' to type 'kernpruefung.Kernpruefung'."
```

Does anybody knows how I could achieve that? I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers!

Comment: In which assembly is `Kernpruefung` declared? If you have declared it in the dynamically loaded DLL, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Sweeper I've created an own C# interface for `Kernpruefung` - I've also tried it with the an own assembly which only declares the interface. Both results into the same error. I just don't know why I can't cast the class instance, which inherits the interface to the interface. It doesn't make sense to me^^

Comment: Okay, so are you sure that `KernpruefungEEL10Impl` actually implements the `Kernpruefung` that you declared, and not some other interface with the same name? Check what assemblies the DLL even references. Does it reference the assembly in which the `Kernpruefung` you created is declared? If not, then it is not possible for `KernpruefungEEL10Impl` to implement your `Kernpruefung`, and it must be implementing some other interface called `Kernpruefung`.

Comment: Alternatively, use reflection on `type`. See if the `Kernpruefung` that it implements come from the same assembly as `typeof(Kernpruefung).Assembly`.